# Uploading large file to Azure db gives error (ASP.NET website)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, azure

I created a simple asp.net website. There's only 1 page, with a file upload control and an upload button. This is how it's supposed to work: When the user browses to the file and clicks upload it will save the actual file to a new record in my AZURE database.

With small files it works fine. With larger files, such as 45mb, it gives the following error....

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired. The timeout period 
elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005):
```

In my web.config I already added the following snippets....

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400000" 
requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="12000" />
</system.web>
```

And….

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

Any idea what could be going on? What am I missing? Are there any additional configurations I need since this is an Azure db?

Sample upload code....

```
    Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
            Dim contentType As String = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType
            Using fs As Stream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream
                Using br As New BinaryReader(fs)
                    Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)
                    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyDb").ConnectionString
                    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
                        Dim query As String = "insert into MyFileTable values (@ActualDocument, @Filename)"
                        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
                            cmd.Connection = con
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActualDocument", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Filename", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename
                            con.Open()
                            Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            Response.Write(i & " records<br/>")
                            con.Close()
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
```

Comment: Is there a reason or requirement to store such large files in a SQL Database?

Comment: I agree with @CSharpRocks. If you have to store large files, try to use OneDrive API to send the files to OneDrive instead of SQL SERVER. You might need a Office365 account

Comment: Can you post the segment of code that you are calling to upload the file.

Comment: Thanks for input. Customer requires Azure and wants to store them in the db. But I will research and present alternatives to him for his consideration. Any suggestions are appreciated! I will post some source soon.

Answer (score 3):

IIS 7 has a cap of 30 MB, see [this link for more info](http://iislogs.com/steveschofield/2007/05/11/iis7-post-40-adjusting-file-upload-size-in-iis7/). The reason for this is that during the upload process, ASP.NET loads the whole file in memory before the user can save the file to the disk or processed further - no streaming in other words. You could try to add the following to a [Azure Role Startup Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180155.aspx):

```
appcmd set config "My Site/MyApp" -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:104857600 -commitpath:apphost
```

to extend beyond the IIS 30 MB limit, but I have not tried it myself.

Comment: Excellent and useful info Inge! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What Inge said makes sense. It could also be a timeout associated with the `SqlCommand`.

Try changing the command timeout: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    // Setting command timeout to 60 seconds
    command.CommandTimeout = 60;
    try {
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException e) {
         // do something with the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting the CommandTimeout seems to work! I will test it further to make sure though.

Answer (score 0):

For .Net core 3, Azure SQL db and entity framework, adding CommandTimeout helped me.

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnectionString"),
    sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(60))
);
```